# invitation type field values is not set in Ror form using session hascode..shows invalid type in ror form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, devise

I have created a form where a form is saved using the hash-code generated form an invitation table:

```
class VectorsController < ApplicationController

def create
    ui = UserInvitation.where(hash_code: session[:hash_code]).first
    @vendor = Vendor.new(vendor_params.merge({user_id: current_user.id, vendor_type: ui.try(:invitation_type)}))

    respond_to do |format|
      if @vendor.save

        ui.completed_registration = true
        ui.save

        session[:hash_code] = nil
        flash[:notice] = "You're all set! Welcome to Availendar!"

        format.html {redirect_to vendor_path(@vendor.id)}
      else
        flash[:alert] = "Oops, looks like there's been a problem. Please correct it and try again."

        format.html {render action: :invited_new}
      end
    end
  end
```

the form claims that `vendor_type` is not valid - but in the `UserInvitation` table the values are already set in `invitation_type` field, yet it shows no value for `vendor_type`...

What could be the reason?  Is it due to session? I just want to set the `invitation_type` from the `UserInvitation` table to be stored as `vendor_type` value in vector controller `/create` action. How to set the value?

Comment: what's the value for `ui.try(:invitation_type)`?

Comment: Builder,Contracts are saved in invitation_type field,UserInvitation table..The values are ther in invitation_type..but it shows value not there

Comment: I'm sorry, I didn't understand your answer - if you add `puts ui.try(:invitation_type)` to your code (after `@vendor = ...`) what is printed?